# Webtop DRL link directly to edit

Tags: documentum, webtop, emc

Is there any way to create a Webtop DRL link so that it instead of asking whether the user wishes to VIEW / EDIT/ ANNOTATE, it goes straight to EDIT mode and just opens up the document, bypassing the question altogether?

Thanks

bgs264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no out of the box drl format for that.

But you can create one yourself, by overloading the drl component so it recoginizes your format and forwards to appropriate logic.

Answer (score 0):

question was  asked and answered on EMC disscussion fourm
https://community.emc.com/thread/128646